# Correct use of the term "converse"?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic

My linear algebra text states the following:

> Suppose $\textbf{x}_1$ is a solution to $A\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}$ and $\textbf{x}_0$ is a solution to $A\textbf{x}=0$. Then $\textbf{x}_1+\textbf{x}_0$ is another solution to $A\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}$
>
> This observation has a useful converse:
>
> Suppose $\textbf{x}_1$ is any particular solution to the system $A\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}$ of linear equations. Then every solution $\textbf{x}_2$ to $A\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}$ has the form $$\textbf{x}_2=\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{x}_1$$ for some solution $\textbf{x}_0$ of the associated homogeneous system $A\textbf{x}=0$.

I don't have much experience doing logic, but as far as I know the converse of $A\rightarrow B$ is simply $B\rightarrow A$. But I don't see how that applies in this case; what they are calling the "converse" looks to me like just a paraphrasing of what they said before. I don't get it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes I was pretty sure of that (a simple Google search confirms it). But what I don't see is how converse applies in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make clear what the statements are and why the word *converse* is correct, rephrase them:

1. If $Ax_1 = b$ and $Ax_0 = 0$ then $A(x_1+x_0) = b$ is another solution:
   $$Ax_1 = b \wedge x_2=x_1+x_0 \wedge \color{maroon}{Ax_0 = 0 \Rightarrow Ax_2 = b}$$
2. (The converse) if $Ax_2 = b$ is a solution and $Ax_1 = b$ then $x_2 = x_1 + x_0$ with $Ax_0 = 0$
   $$Ax_1 = b \wedge x_2=x_1+x_0 \wedge \color{blue}{Ax_2 = b \Rightarrow Ax_0 = 0}$$

The "turning" of the arrow happens with the mutual premise that $Ax_1 = b$ and that $x_2 = x_0 + x_1$.

The two statements can also be viewed as mutual set-inclusions for the sets
$$M_1 := \{x_1 + x | Ax = 0\}\\
M_2 := \{x | Ax = b\}$$
With the premise $Ax_1 = b$ we have the first statement as $M_1 \subset M_2$ and the second as its converse, $M_2 \subset M_1$. Both combined give the equality $M_1 = M_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Rephrasing is the hard part -- I understand your answer but it's difficult for me to see how you achieved it from the wording used in the text!

Comment: @yroc For example "$x_1$ [to be] a solution to $Ax=b$" just means $Ax_1 = b$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the converse of $A \Rightarrow B$ is $B \Rightarrow A$.

The statement isn't really saying that $A \vec{x}_{2} = A\vec{x}_{0} + A\vec{x}_{1} = \vec{b}$ IMPLIES $A\vec{x}_{0} = \vec{0}$ and $A\vec{x}_{1} = \vec{b}$. We can't start from the lhs and deduce the rhs, what are $\vec{x}_{0}$ and $\vec{x}_{1}$ anyway? We didn't define them on the lhs, we just wrote $\vec{x}_{2} = \vec{x}_{0} + \vec{x}_{1}$ for some arbitrary $\vec{x}_{0}$ and $\vec{x}_{1}$. The statement of your textbook is simply saying that any solution of a non-homogeneous equation can be written as the solution of the homogeneous equation plus a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation.

If you have taken an ODE's course, there is often similar reasoning there: a solution of a linear ODE can be written as $y(x) = y_{h}(x) + y_{n}(x)$ where $y_{h}$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation and $y_{n}$ is a particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation. It might seem pointless that we decide to include a solution to the homogeneous equation, but it is in fact very important. The GENERAL solution to a linear equation is the sum of its homogeneous solution plus a non-homogeneous solution, if we didn't include the homogeneous solution then we wouldn't have the MOST GENERAL solution.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, this is helpful -- thank you!